# How to add 2 onclick functions

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>A452 Question 2 - Arrays</h1>

<p>Array of Products:</p>
<p id="prod"></p>
<p id="prod2"></p>
<p id="prod3"></p>
<p id="text1"></p>
<p id="text2"></p>

<script>
var products = ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Keyboard","Monitor","Mouse"];
document.getElementById("prod").innerHTML = products
</script>

<button type = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('prod2').innerHTML = products.sort();">
Turn list in alphabetical order!</button>

<button type = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('prod3').innerHTML = products.length;">
Count the number of items in the list!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I add a string of text before each onclick event.
For example the output for the second button is "6" while i want it to be "the number of items in the list is: 6"

Comment: Basic string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat the string:

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('prod3').innerHTML = 'the number of items in the list is: ' + products.length;">Count the number of items in the list!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello put the text between 'text' and after add + .
like this:

```
<button type = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('prod3').innerHTML = 'the number of items in the list is: ' + products.length;">
```